# How to refresh the tkinter table in specific interval(for updation)?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

Spec:

Python3,
Postgresql,
psycopg2,
tkinnter

Thanks in advance

```
class MultiColumnListbox(object):
"""use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

def __init__(self):
    self.tree = None
    self._setup_widgets()
    self._build_tree()

def _setup_widgets(self):
    s = """WOW CALL LIST"""
    msg = ttk.Label(wraplength="4i", justify="left", anchor="n",
        padding=(10, 2, 10, 6), text=s)
    msg.pack(fill='x')
    container = ttk.Frame()
    container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
        command=self.tree.yview)
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
        command=self.tree.xview)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
        xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
    hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)



 def _build_tree(self):



        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adsjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)

def sortby(tree, col, descending):
    """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
    # grab values to sort
    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    # if the data to be sorted is numeric change to float
    #data =  change_numeric(data)
    # now sort the data in place
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \
        int(not descending)))

# the test data ...

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='wowcall' user='postgres' password='Admin@123'")   
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM wowdata")
car_list = cur.fetchall()


car_header = ['WOW ID',' Agent Name','Customer No']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("WOW Call")
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

How to refresh the table automatically in specific time interval?

How to refresh the table automatically in specific time interval?
How to refresh the table automatically in specific time interval?

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that refreshes the table. Within that function, have it call itself with `after`:

```
def refresh_table():
    <do whatever you need to refresh the table>

    # call again in 10 seconds
    root.after(10000, refresh_table)
```

Then, call the function once and it will run until the program exits.

```
refresh_table()
```

Comment: I wonder if you would have to tell Tkinter not to update screen as you update thousands of records in view. Then turn updating view back on after you've updates all the rows?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: that is effectively what happens by default. Tkinter is single-threaded, so while you are in the process of updating the window, the window changes are buffered until control returns to the event loop. Then, all screen updates happen at once.